# pardot api to return all folder names for all lists

Tags: rest-api, pardot, folder

I have a request asking if it is possible via a Pardot rest api call to get a response where it contains the list and the folder it belongs.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no, folders aren't visible in Pardot API in any form.